# How can I modify my WHILE loop to include more columns from my SELECT statement?

Tags: c#, vb.net

This is probably easy but I am having issues with it.

Here is sql bit:

```
Dim strSQL As String = ("SELECT field1 FROM myTable WHERE key like '%' + strkey + '%'")


    While oReader.Read()
        With oReader
            Dim li As New ListItem(oReader(0).ToString())
            fday.Items.Add(li)

        End With 'end With
    End While 'End While
```

Then on markup page, I have this:

```
   <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="fday" style="text-align:center;cursor:pointer;color:blue;text-decoration:underline;" CssClass="checkAll"> 
   </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

This works fine.

However, we have been asked to add more fields so we have additional controls on the markup page.

For instance:

```
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
           <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="fday" style="text-align:center;cursor:pointer;color:blue;text-decoration:underline;" CssClass="checkAll"> 
   </asp:CheckBoxList>
   </td>
   <td><asp:TextBox id="tb3" runat="server" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

This way, we can have more columns of data by adding more columns to the query, like select field1, field2, etc from mytable

How do I modify the WHILE loop to include the additional columns in my query?

Hope my explanation is clear.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't have to. `oReader(1)` will contain the new column. The object exposes an index operator to the underlying sql data.

Comment: the while loop itself is fine, but you might want to add a secondary loop under it to grab the individual fields from `oReader(i)` i going from 0 to however many fields there are.  That is, unless you want to hard code them.  If you know exactly how many fields there will be, then hardcoding works great.  Also, dont forget to change the SQL statement to grab the new data as well.

Comment: @Nevyn, an example please if you don't mind.
 
asawyer, I tried that it didn't work.

the textbox on markup is not getting populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping in mind that I dont know anything about what your other code looks like, Here is my best guess at an example.

```
Dim strSQL As String = ("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE key like '%' + strkey + '%'")

Dim i as integer
i = 0

While oReader.Read()
    With oReader
        while true
            Dim li As New ListItem(oReader(i).ToString())
            if (li is Nothing)//isNull check
                break
            else
                fday.Items.Add(li)
        End While 
    End With 
End While
```

2 other things to keep in mind.  Im primarily a C# programmer, so if this looks weird or uses things that have a different equivalent in VB, please translate it yourself.  The other, Im not sure what oReader is, or what kind of behavior it will have if `i` is out of Range. It is very likely that this code will read in all the columns then generate an IndexOutOfRangeException.

**----**

if you know EXACTLY how many columns there will be, its better to use a for loop with strict bounds, than a while loop.  `for i = 0; i < X; i++` where X is the number of columns you actually have.

**----**

Now, the big problem we have, is that you have described this in an odd way, and you forgot to add an asp.Net tag to this.  What you need is NOT actually a while loop, that would only work if you wanted to add more columns of things to fDay.  If you are dealing with generics, you need to create generics, otherwise you need to have everything hard coded.

```
Dim strSQL As String = ("SELECT field1, field2 FROM myTable WHERE key like '%' + strkey + '%'")

While oReader.Read()
    With oReader
        Dim li As New ListItem(oReader(0).ToString())
        fday.Items.Add(li)

        Dim txt as New TextBox()
        txt.Text = oReader(1).ToString()
        //store txt somewhere permanent?
    End With 'end With
End While 'End While
```

Im assuming this is more like what you want.  If this isn't it either, get significantly more specific about the data structure you are dealing with and what each row of data actually contains.  You may (probably) need a different data structure for fDay in order to hold the new data so that each record displays ALL the fields and not just 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nevyn. Yes, this second solution is more like what I want and txt.text is getting populated with values but i need it to be an added column, not a part of the <li>

More like Column1   Column2 instead of:

Column1
Column2

I will try table and see if that fixes it.

Comment: < what I am trying to say is that right now txt is displaying just one record.

It needs to display all records associated with fday.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you should be using a TextBox then...or that you should be creating a NEW textbox for every record, which is what this code is intended to do.  The storage and display method I left up to you though.  If you are only getting 1 textbox, check your creation and storage.  If the text in the box is always the same...check your data.  If you need multiple records in the one column, you might not want to be using textBox, I was just going off of your explanation/example.

Comment: The other bit...you have neither displayed, nor explained, how you are taking the objects created in the data read and creating them as Display objects on the markup page.  I dont have a clue what you are doing there, but its sounds like the issue could be with that code instead...